# Mathematica stops working while exporting a graphic in pdf format. Why?

Tags: export, graphics3d

I have drawn a graphic and want to save it as a pdf file, but each time this message appears: Mathematica stopped working. Then the program is closed. I should mention that Mathematica worked for simpler graphics with fewer elements. I wonder if it is due to the complexity of graphics.
It is also possible to save it in other formats, say, JEPG, but the resolution is not satisfactory.

```
Show[
{Graphics3D[
{Green, Arrowheads[0.05], 
Arrow[Tube[{{-6, 2.5, .5}, {-4, 2.5, .5}}, 0.1]]}, Boxed -> False],
Graphics3D[
{Green, Arrowheads[0.07], 
 Arrow[Tube[{{4, 2.5, .5}, {8, 2.5, .5}}, 0.15]]}, Boxed -> False],
Graphics3D[
{Red, Arrowheads[0.05], 
Arrow[Tube[{{-6, 4.5, .5}, {-4, 4.5, .5}}, 0.1]]}, Boxed -> False],
Graphics3D[
{Red, Arrowheads[0.07], 
Arrow[Tube[{{4, 4.5, .5}, {8, 4.5, .5}}, 0.15]]}, Boxed -> False],
Graphics3D[
 {{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 1}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 7, -1}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 3, 0}, {4, 4, 1}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 5, 0}, {4, 7, 1}]},
{Cyan, Opacity[.8], Cuboid[{-4, 2, 0}, {4, 3, 1}]},
{Yellow, Opacity[.8], Cuboid[{-4, 4, 0}, {4, 5, 1}]}},
Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]}
]
```

Comment: How are you saving the file? Also, Mathematica version and OS would be useful information. I don't encounter any issues when I try to use `Export` or `File | Save Selection As`.

Comment: That does not happen for me with Mathematica 11.3 on macOS but I guess this issue is very OS-dependent. This graphic is not too complex (although the `Tube`s introduce quite many polygons). Does it work if you drop the transparent elements?

Comment: It exports just fine with *Mathematica* 11.3 on Windows 10.  What you might want to do is add "ImageSize->2400" to the first `Graphics3D` command which will help with any resolution issues for any desired output format.  You should add your `Export` command or whatever command you're using to to export the graphic.

Comment: When I added the imagesize, the error message did not appear. I'm using Mathematica 11.1 on Windows 7. Maybe it is too old.